# Least squares problem- show there is a single projection onto col(A)

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that even when there are infinite solutions to a least squares problem: MIN||Ax-b||, for every two solutions $x_1, x_2: Ax_1=Ax_2$.

I understand the intuition for why it's true but i struggle to prove it. thanks!

Comment: Try showing that in any subspace $S$, there is a unique vector $y$ which minimizes $\|y-b\|^2$. Hint: Proof by contradiction.

Comment: this is what i tried to show but i am missing something.
||b-v1||=||b-v2||
and then i open the norm and i don't know how to proceed.
@Rahul

Comment: Can you show that if $v_1,v_2$ lie in a subspace and are equidistant from $b$, then $(v_1+v_2)/2$ lies in the same subspace and is closer to $b$?

Comment: thanks! i'll try
@Rahul